# Exact sequence of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R= \mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$. Let $A$ be an abelian group. Consider the exact sequence $$0 \to A \to R \to R \to 0.$$ Then $A$ must be zero.

It seems correct but can anyone produce a counterexample?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Both $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ have the following property (P):

If $x$ and $y$ are non-zero in $R$, there are non-zero integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ax = by$.

Now let $\phi: R \rightarrow R$ denote the surjective map. This implies there exists an $x \in R$ such that $\phi(x) = 1$. Now assume that the kernel is non-trivial, so there exists an $y \in 0$ with $\phi(y) = 0$. Condition (P) then implies that

$$0 \ne a = a \phi(x) = \phi(ax) = \phi(by) = b \phi(y) = 0.$$

Comment: Nice. Maybe you should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's name the arrows,

$$
0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} R \xrightarrow{g} R \to 0.
$$

By exactness,

$$
\ker g = \operatorname{im} f \simeq A/\ker f \simeq A.
$$

To conclude we ought to see that $g$ must be injective.

The endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ are determined by the image of $1$. If $|g(1)| \geq 2$ you can check that $1 \not \in \operatorname{im}{g}$. So by surjectivity it must be $g(1) \in \{1,-1\}$ and so $g = id$ or $g = -id$, both injective. (A fancier argument is to say that since $\mathbb{Z}$ is free, the endomorphism ought to be a retraction, hence the sequence splits and in particular $A$ has to be free of rank zero.)

As for $\mathbb{Q}$, let $p/q$ be an arbitrary rational. by surjectivity, necessarily we get that $g(1) \neq 0$. Then,

$$
qg(1/q) = g(1/q) + \dots + g(1/q) = g(1/q + \cdots + 1/q) = g(1)
$$

which says that $g(1/q) = g(1)/q$. Therefore, we obtain

$$
g(p/q) = g(1/q) + \dots + g(1/q) = pg(1/q) = g(1) \cdot p/q.
$$

This proves that

$$
h(p/q) := g(1)^{-1}p/q
$$

is an inverse of $g$, in particular, the latter is injective.